# Kafka Connect without schema, only JSON

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I want to use JDBC sink connector with JSON and without schema.
They write ([source](https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/userguide.html#json-without-sr)):

> If you need to use JSON without Schema Registry for Connect data, you
> can use the JsonConverter supported with Kafka.  The example below
> shows the JsonConverter key and value properties that are added to the
> configuration:
>
> key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
> value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
> key.converter.schemas.enable=false
> value.converter.schemas.enable=false
>
> When the properties key.converter.schemas.enable and
> value.converter.schemas.enable are set to true,  the key or value is
> not treated as plain JSON, but rather as a composite JSON object
> containing both  an internal schema and the data. When these are
> enabled for a source connector, both the schema and  data are in the
> composite JSON object. When these are enabled for a sink connector,
> the schema and  data are extracted from the composite JSON object.
> Note that this implementation never uses Schema Registry.
>
> When the properties key.converter.schemas.enable and
> value.converter.schemas.enable are set to false (the default),  only
> the data is passed along, without the schema. This reduces the payload
> overhead for applications that do not need a schema.

I configured connector:

```
{
  "name": "noschemajustjson",
  "config": {
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "schemas.enable": "false",
    "name": "noschemajustjson",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "config.action.reload": "restart",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "topics": "testconnect2",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres",
    "connection.user": "postgres",
    "connection.password": "********",
    "dialect.name": "PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect",
    "table.name.format": "utp",
    "auto.create": "false",
    "auto.evolve": "false"
  }
}
```

But I still get error:

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Sink
> connector 'noschemajustjson2' is configured with
> 'delete.enabled=false' and 'pk.mode=none' and therefore requires
> records with a non-null Struct value and non-null Struct schema, but
> found record at
> (topic='testconnect2',partition=0,offset=0,timestamp=1626416739697)
> with a HashMap value and null value schema.

So what should I do to force Connect work without schema at all (only plain JSON)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to use JDBC sink connector with JSON and **without schema**

You cannot do this - the JDBC Sink connector streams to a relational database, and relational databases have schemas :-D The JDBC Sink connector therefore *requires* a schema to be present for the data.

Depending on where your data is coming from you have different options.

- If it's ingested from Kafka Connect, use a converter that supports schemas (Avro, Protobuf, JSON Schema)
- If it's produced by an application that you have control over, get that application to serialise that data with a schema (Avro, Protobuf, JSON Schema)
- If it's coming from somewhere you don't have control over then you'll need to pre-process the topic to add an explicit schema and write it to a new topic that is then consumed by the JDBC Sink connector.

References & resources:

- [Kafka Connect JDBC Sink deep-dive: Working with Primary Keys](https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/)
- [Applying a schema to JSON data with ksqlDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-3qN_tlYR4&t=1683s)