# Is it possible to Consume data using JDBC connector using Schema Registry, If a JAVA producer is producing data without Schema?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

My requirement is when a producer is producing data without schema , I need to register a new schema  in Schema- Register to consume data into JDBC converter.

Have [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68405006/kafka-connect-without-schema-only-json), but is it possible to get any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Schema Registry is not a requirement to use JDBC Connector, but JDBC Sink connector does **require** a schema in the record payload, as the linked answer says.

The source connector can read data and generate records without a schema, but this has no interaction with any external producer client.

---

If you have producers that generate records without any schema, then it's unclear what schema you would be registering anywhere. But you can try to use a `ProducerInterceptor` to intercept and inspect those records to do whatever you need to.